# Did people go back to where they were?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Did the Unsnap in *Avengers: Endgame* put everyone back to the place they were when they were Snapped?

Dr. Strange and Peter Parker were on Titan when they were Snapped, so did Dr. Strange create a portal all the way from Titan to Earth?

Or did Banner include putting people back where they "belong" as part of the Unsnap?

Comment: Anyone snapped away in a plane wouldn't come back, although at least they can get a proper burial this time.

Comment: They got back. But where did everyone (like Black Panther and Asgardians) get so their portals?

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi: Planets themselves were not at the same place when people were unsnapped...

Comment: Well I wouldn't want to be the guy who got snapped away while being on a public toilet/in a dressing room/a bathroom/...   But it is best not to think too much about the logic of things in this movie. "Logic, you have been weighed on the scales and found wanting." - Everyone with half a brain

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Did the Unsnap in Avengers: Endgame put everyone back to the place they were when they were Snapped?

### It appears so.

If you look through the "portals" opened by the sorcerers' sling-rings you can see where they are coming from.

**GotG & Spiderman from Titan**

[image]

**Valkyrie & Asgardians from New Asgard**

[image]

**Black Panther & Shuri from Wakanda**

[image]

**Wong & other sorcerers from Kamar-Taj(?)**

[image]

This appears to be from where they were "snapped" and/or currently living.

Comment: [Sucks for some people I guess :)](https://img.ifcdn.com/images/41f2fd2a2e937499a6cda4d7a859510712cecf23b728dceb72952323a745b4c0_1.jpg)

Comment: ... wait, were all the Asgardians snapped at New Asgard? I thought that's where they settled *after* the snappening?

Comment: @muru Valkyrie wasn't snapped, so a lot of the Asgardians emerging from that portal (maybe all) are the ones who didn't get snapped.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg ha! Maybe the sorcerers were spending the time between the reverse snap and final battle catching people falling from the sky.

Comment: @muru I don't think Asgardians were snapped at all. At the start of Infinity War Thanos already killed half of the Asgardians on that ship. I believe Thanos did not snap away races which he already "halved" "manually"

Comment: But who were those Asgardian soldiers? I thought Hela killed all of them, and only civilians remained? Did they train new soldiers in New Asgard?

Comment: @ArthurShveida if the directors can be trusted anymore, they were snapped too. https://twitter.com/DorianParksnRec/status/1068032266201255936

Comment: @muru Oh snap. I didn't know that. Poor Asgardians :(
In that case, even if they disappeared in space, it looks like they re-appeared in New Asgard, as per `Nikhil Eshvar's` answer

Comment: I feel almost certain that a better quality version of this film is available now, that you can post improved screengrabs from

Answer (score 14):

Based on [Kevin Feige's AMA (Ask me anything)](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/ennasj9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), "Smart" Hulk brought everyone back and also brought them to a *safe place*.

Comment: Mr. Feige in all honours, but seeing the other answer and the, let's say, fuzziness of that linked Reddit question, this seems more like a throwaway remark by him in order to prevent nitpicks/concerns like "what if some dude reappeared in mid air" rather than a clear statement that people actually got transported to entirely different places. The surface of Titan could for all intents and purposes actually *be* a "safe place", but it's not clear if that's what Feige means. To be clear, this is defnitely a useful interview, but it could use a little more critical reflection in the answer.

Comment: This is most critical for the Asgardians, who were in deep space at the time of the Snap.

Answer (score 6):

Excellent answer by Paulie_D and I would like to add one more thing.

Although there is a considerable amount of time between Hulk's (un) snap and all the Avengers returning through portals to fight, we immediately see the effects of (un)snap with the phone call from Laura, Clint's wife.

So, she returns to the same place in her home backyard along with her kids but finds that Clint is absent so, she immediately calls him from her cell phone.

Comment: And somebody paid her cell phone plan all those years.  Or else Hawkeye re-upped it

Comment: He could have simply had the house number saved as "Laura"... If you're the bread winner and frequently out working (or being a gd superhero), it's not unusual to save the house number in your significant others name.

Comment: If Professor Hulk can unsnap everyone to a safe place, of course he can unsnap all of their phone contracts, mortgages, legal declarations of death, etc too.

Comment: Her cell plan was probably on an auto pay from an account that didn't get closed. Her gym membership was also being paid.

Answer (score 6):

When the Avengers show up, Peter Parker says this to Tony Stark when they meet:

> You will not believe what's been going on.
>   Do you remember when we were in space?
>   And I got all dusty? I must've passed
>   out, 'cause I woke up, and you were gone.
>   But Doctor Strange was there, right?
>   He was like,
>   "It's been five years.
>   Come on, they need us!"
>   And then he started doing the yellow
>   sparkly thing that he does all the time...

So yes, at least the Guardians + Peter + Dr. Strange were brought back where they vanished so I would assume everybody else was as well